# C structs: Can a function argument be used to deference a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm learning about OOP C and I want to write the equivalent of getters and setters. 
I have the following struct.

```
typedef struct {
    int item0;
    int item1;
    int item2;
    etc...;

} ItemsStr;
typedef ItemsStr * ItemsPtr;

items_get_item(ItemsPtr item, itemname) {
    return item->itemname;
}
```

I realize that the syntax is invalid but is there a way to accomplish the above?
I also realize that I could write a switch statement but I was wondering if there was a way to use the parameter passed in to deference.

Comment: Your `struct` members are the same type. You could use an array and refer to the elements with `enum` definitions.

Comment: Symbols' names are gone after compilation.

Comment: OOP is quite related to dynamic dispatch (or class polymorphism).  You might want to have something similar to [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)s. But YMMV, since you don't define what is OOP C.

Comment: @Antii Haapala thanks for the duplicate mark. Those links answer my question exactly? Should duplicate questions be deleted?

Comment: Why do you think OOP requires to write a generic getter/setter? Encapsulation does not require existence of generic getter/setter method. In most cases it will go against OOP paradigm - user of the object does not need to know the internal data representation

Comment: @ Artemy Vysotsky I was more curious about accessing struct fields at runtime but did not know how to phrase it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetof()`:

```
int items_get_item(ItemsPtr items, size_t offset) {
    return *(int*)((char*)items + offset);
}
```

Then the caller does this:

```
items_get_item(items, offsetof(ItemsStr, item1))
```

Comment: thanks this works the way I imagined.

Comment: could you explain how the dereferencing in this case works please?